# Gaussian Random matrix and PDFs of its elements

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, random-matrices

I have $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ i.i.d normal random variables of mean 0 and variance 1 and the following transformations where $U$, $V$, $W$, $\theta$ and $G_{11}$, $G_{12}$, $G_{21}$, and $G_{22}$ are random variables
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\boldsymbol{A} & \boldsymbol{B} \\
\boldsymbol{C} & \boldsymbol{D}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \boldsymbol{\theta} & \sin \theta \\
-\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
U & V \\
0 & W
\end{array}\right]
$$

and
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\boldsymbol{G}_{11} & \boldsymbol{G}_{12} \\
\boldsymbol{G}_{12} & \boldsymbol{G}_{22}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\boldsymbol{A} & \boldsymbol{B} \\
\boldsymbol{C} & \boldsymbol{D}
\end{array}\right]^{T}\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\boldsymbol{A} & \boldsymbol{B} \\
\boldsymbol{C} & \boldsymbol{D}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\boldsymbol{U} & \boldsymbol{V} \\
\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{W}
\end{array}\right]^{T}\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\boldsymbol{U} & \boldsymbol{V} \\
\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{W}
\end{array}\right]
$$
I would like to find the PDF of $U$, $V$, and the conditional PDF of $G_{12}$ given $G_{11}$ and $G_{22}$.

The problem is that I don't even know how to proceed. One way is to go with Jacobian but the issue is how to inverse the matrices of RV?
Any suggestion??

Comment: Do you know the distribution of $\theta$?

Comment: No, it is unknown. All I know is that A, B, C, and D are i.i.d Normal random variables.

Comment: Yes, the mean and variance is the same for A, B, C, and D. I have no idea about $\theta$ All I know is the those matrices decomposition.

Comment: Is the mean of $A,B,C,D$ equal to $0$?

Comment: Yes, the mean is 0 and the variance is 1